# How many page frames does the system have for user process?

Tags: operating-systems

**Operating System MCQ Question:**
If a system has 1 GB RAM with a page size of 8KB and operating system occupies 16 MB of RAM, how many page frames does the system have for user process?
a. 129024
b. 120924
c. 131072
d. 119864

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem so far, and what conceptual issue do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User space = 1 GB- 16 MB = 1008 MB
Page Frame = 1008 MB / 8 KB = 129024

Answer (score 0):

RAM = user + OS

totalSpace/pageFrames = pageSize

First, find out how much user space you have by subtracting out the 16 MB from 1GB. Then take that difference and divide it by the page size to get the number of frames.

Comment: `how much user space` for a (one) *user process* (see question) or (*all*?) *user processes*?